# Can I require a module level controller in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am still trying to figure out the roles of controllers, modules, services, etc, in Angular JS.

I am trying to require a controller inside of my directive. The controller I am trying to reference is a part of the same module as the directive, so I would assume this would "just work":

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <direct>
        ABC
    </direct>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = "Hello World!";
});

myApp.directive('direct', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        element.on("mouseenter", function() {
            alert(ctrl.data);
        });
    };
    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        require: 'MyCtrl', 
        template: '<div>Alert!</div>'
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to reference some data from "MyCtrl" when you mouse over the directive.

However, on page load I get the [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$compile/ctreq?p0=MyCtrl&p1=direct):

```
Error: $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller
Controller 'MyCtrl', required by directive 'direct', can't be found!
```

So Angular cannot find the "MyCtrl" control. I had assumed since we're in the scope of the "myApp" module that Angular would just pick up on this controller, but apparently not?

In this simplified example it may seem like I want to use controller: "MyCtrl", however this is not the case. I want to be able to access data in the "MyCtrl" without it being the controller for this directive (semantically speaking it wouldn't make sense for "MyCtrl" to be the controller for this directive).

Is there some other requirement for this to work that I'm missing?

Comment: Based on the docs; I think require is supposed to refer to another directive and that the two directives need to be used in conjunction with each other. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive .  I'll add that it sounds like you're trying to add an external dependency to your directive; which often defeats the purpose of encapsulation.

Comment: @Reboog711 Ah so this only works when you're trying to require a service?
I'll elaborate on my intentions - I'm trying to make it so I can pass data between controllers, which I don't _think_ is breaking encapsulation. For example, if I have a menu object and a user adds an item to their order, I want to be able to say "the user added menu item <id> to their order" (a rough example, but you get the idea).
After looking into it more I _think_ what I want is a service.

Comment: Sharing data between controllers should use a Service or Factory; so I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.data = "Hello World!";
});

myApp.directive('direct', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        element.on("mouseenter", function() {
            alert(ctrl.data);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        controller: 'MyCtrl', 
        template: '<div>Alert!</div>'
    }
});
```

Here's a [CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/hjjbzb7i) that demos this code.

All that being said, this strikes me as being an unusual use case for a directive controller. I suspect this just scratch code to demonstrate the concept, but typically you only would use directive controllers if you need to expose behaviors or properties on a parent directive to a child directive.

Finally, worth noting that it's considered best practice to avoid introducing global variables like you've done here with `var myApp`. Just use method chaining.

Comment: This is actually creating another instance for the controller, the variables you modify on that controller will not affect the other one. http://jsfiddle.net/amatiasq/2dq9w4r2/